# Apple Magic Mouse interferred by heavy processing

Tags: macos, magic-mouse

I have discovered that my Apple Magic Mouse seems to 'stutter' and become less responsive during periods when my macbook pro is doing heavy processing.  For example now when I am installing Xcode 4.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not ever encountered this myself but I think that if you cut down on the applications you are running in the background when doing the processor heavy task you can somewhat fix the issue.