# Mighty Mouse is jumping around on screen

Tags: macos, mouse, mighty-mouse

I have a really annoying problem with my mighty mouse since a couple of weeks now. When moving my mouse (mightymouse) sometimes it jumps (about once in 30minutes) directly to a (propably) random spot of my screen. I cleaned the mightymouse several times and there is definately no hair or the like, and the desk is not the problem as well - I have the same problem with my other mighty mouse at home. Since I don't have any other mouse i couldn't test whether this relates to the mighty mouse or the mouse in general.

Has anyone experienced such issues as well? Is there a solution?

Greetings

btw: Mac OS X 10.6.4

## update

I confirm that the surface is not the problem. I used a sheet of paper and the problem remained.

Comment: what surface are you using ? Does it improve when using something underneath that's easier to track ?

Comment: I don't think the surface is a problem. I know by experience how the mouse behaves on gradients or the like on the surface. It's not a weird movement, rather an instant jump that comes from time to time and cannot be reproduced by simply moving over the same spot again. Nevertheless I'll use a sheet of paper to absolutely exclude the surface as a problem.

Comment: post updated. Surface is not the problem…

Comment: It's not the stuttering described [here](http://superuser.com/questions/224410/apple-magic-mouse-interferred-by-heavy-processing), is it? I know that's about the magic mouse, but it just sounded so similar.

Comment: @daniel nope. It is really an instant jump. The distance is also totally random.

Comment: It would be useful to use a different mouse to test if the problem persists. I would ask that you make every effort to do so.

Comment: Is your mouse wired or wireless?